# Deploy An angular project to multiple firebase hosting with `ng deploy`

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-cli, angularfire, firebase-hosting

I prepared two firebase projects for development and production. And I want to deploy them with `ng deploy --configuration=<environment>`. At first, I added `angularfire` with `ng add @angular/fire` and configured well for the first project. Then I edit `firebase.json` `.firebaserc`, `angular.json` as follows.

`firebase.json`

```
{
  "hosting": [
   {
      "target": "<my-angular-project>"
      "public": "dist/<my-angular-project>" 
   },
   ...
 ]
}
```

`.firebaserc`

```
{
  "projects": {
    "production": "<firebase-prodution-project>",
    "development": "<firebase-development-project>",
    "default": "<firebase-prodution-project>"
  },
  "targets": {
    "<firebase-prodution-project>": {
      "hosting": {
        "<my-angular-project>": [
          "<firebase-producion-project-web-app>"
        ]
      }
    },
    "<firebase-development-project>": {
      "hosting": {
        "<my-angular-project>": [
          "<firebase-development-project-web-app>"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "etags": {}
}
```

`angular.json`

```
{
 ...
 "projects": {
    "<my-angular-project>": {
       ...
       "architect": {
          ...
          "deploy": {
             "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
             "options": {
                 ...
                 "browserTarget": "<my-angular-project>:build:development",
                 "buildTarget": "<my-angular-project>:build:development",
                 "firebaseProject": "<firebase-development-project>",
                 "firebaseHostingSite": "<firebase-development-project-web-app>"
             },
             "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "browserTarget": "<my-angular-project>:build:production",
                  "firebaseProject": "<firebase-prodution-project>",
                  "firebaseHostingSite": "<firebase-prodution-project-web-app>"
                },
                "development": {
                  "browserTarget": "<my-angular-project>:build:development",
                  "firebaseProject": "<firebase-development-project>",
                  "firebaseHostingSite": "<firebase-development-project-web-app>",
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
  } 
}
```

As far as I tried, `ng deploy --configuration=production` works fine. But `ng deploy --configuration=development` throws an error:
`An unhandled exception occurred: The Firebase Project specified by your angular.json or .firebaserc is in conflict`

Is there something I missed or I broke something?

I tried `firebase use` to manual switch two firebase projects, run `ng add @angular/fire`.

I expect successful deployments to two environments through switching `ng deploy --configuration=<environment>`

[same problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75174677/deploying-to-multiple-firebase-sites-using-angularfire-and-ng-deploy)

packages

- @angular/fire ^7.5.0
- @angular/cli ^15.2.0

global dependency

- firebase-tools@11.24.0

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "project",
      "public": "dist/project",
      "ignore": ["**/.*"],
    }
  ]
}
```

**angular.json**

```
...
  "build": {
    ...
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        "fileReplacements": [
          {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
          }
        ],
        ...
      },
      "stage": {
        "fileReplacements": [
          {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.stage.ts"
          }
        ],
        ...
      },
    },
    "defaultConfiguration": "production"
  },
...
  "deploy": {
    "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
    "options": {
      "version": 2,
      "browserTarget": "servire:build"
    }
  },
...
```

**.firebaserc**

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "project-abc",
    "production": "project-abc",
    "stage": "project-xyz"
  },
  "targets": {
    "project-xyz": {
      "hosting": {
        "project": [
          "project-site-stage"
        ]
      }
    },
    "servire-abc": {
      "hosting": {
        "project": [
          "project-site-production"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "etags": {}
}
```

**Terminal**

```
ng build --configuration=production && firebase deploy -P production // Prod deployment
ng build --configuration=stage && firebase deploy -P stage // Stage deployment
```